# Нужно чтобы при нажатии на один QCheckBox, второй QCheckBox не мог нажиматься

Tags: python, gui, pyqt, сигналы-слоты, qcheckbox

Помогите реализовать чтобы при нажатии на один `QCheckBox`, второй чекбокс не мог нажиматься.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Делаю калькулятор расхода калорий, в котором нужно указать свой пол. Хотел осуществить данную задачу с помощью checkBox из PyQt5, но из-за слабых знаний PyQt5 не выходит.
Из кода есть только расположение чекбоксов

Comment: setCheckable(False) или setEnabled(False)

Comment: Как осуществить цикл?

Comment: Если вы хотите получать быстрые и правильные ответы, пожалуйста публикуйте код, который у вас уже написан.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> void QCheckBox::stateChanged(int state)
>
> Этот сигнал испускается всякий раз, когда изменяется состояние флажка,
> то есть всякий раз, когда пользователь проверяет или снимает флажок.

> enabled : bool
>
> Это свойство указывает, включен ли виджет.
> Обычно включенный виджет обрабатывает события клавиатуры и мыши;
> отключенный виджет - нет. Исключение составляет QAbstractButton.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.checkOne = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('one')
        self.checkTwo = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('two')
        
        self.vlayout  = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.checkOne)
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.checkTwo)
        self.setLayout(self.vlayout)
        
        self.checkOne.stateChanged.connect(self.selectBooks1)            # !!!
        self.checkTwo.stateChanged.connect(self.selectBooks2)            # !!!

    def selectBooks1(self, toggle):
        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            print('checked 1')
            self.checkTwo.setEnabled(False)                              # !!!
        else:
            print('unchecked 1')
            self.checkTwo.setEnabled(True)                               # !!!

    def selectBooks2(self, toggle):
        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            print('checked 2')
            self.checkOne.setEnabled(False)
        else:
            print('unchecked 2')
            self.checkOne.setEnabled(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Noob пожалуйста, предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимые примеры. Если мой ответы добавляют вам новых знаний, не забывайте отмечать их и как полезный.

Comment: Хорошо, учту, просто я здесь недавно